# How to use subquery In Sphinx's multi-valued attributes (MVA) for query type

Tags: postgresql, subquery, search-engine, sphinx

**My database is PostgreSQL, and I want to use Sphinx Search Engines to index my data;**

How can i use [sql_attr_multi](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/conf-sql-attr-multi.html) to fetch the relationship data?

The tables in postgresql,  schemas is:

```
crm=# \d orders
                                   Table "orders"
     Column      |            Type             |               Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------
 id              | bigint                      | not null
 trade_id        | bigint                      | not null
 item_id         | bigint                      | not null
 price           | numeric(10,2)               | not null
 total_amount    | numeric(10,2)               | not null
 subject         | character varying(255)      | not null default ''::character varying
 status          | smallint                    | not null default 0
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "orders_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "orders_trade_id_idx" btree (trade_id)




crm=# \d trades
                                     Table "trades"
        Column         |            Type             |               Modifiers
-----------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------
 id                    | bigint                      | not null
 operator_id           | bigint                      | not null
 customer_id           | bigint                      | not null
 category_ids          | bigint[]                    | not null
 total_amount          | numeric(10,2)               | not null
 discount_amount       | numeric(10,2)               | not null
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 updated_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "trades_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The Sphinx's config is:

```
source trades_src
{
  type        = pgsql
  sql_host    = 10.10.10.10
  sql_user    = ******
  sql_pass    = ******
  sql_db      = crm
  sql_port    = 5432

  sql_query   = \
    SELECT id, operator_id, customer_id, category_ids, total_amount, discount_amount, \
         date_part('epoch',created_at) AS created_at, \
         date_part('epoch',updated_at) AS updated_at \
      FROM public.trades;

  #attributes
  sql_attr_bigint = operator_id
  sql_attr_bigint = customer_id

  sql_attr_float  = total_amount
  sql_attr_float  = discount_amount


  sql_attr_multi = bigint category_ids from field category_ids

  #sql_attr_multi = bigint order_ids from query; SELECT id FROM orders
  #how can i add where condition is the query for orders? eg. WHERE trade_id = ?


  sql_attr_timestamp  = created_at
  sql_attr_timestamp  = updated_at
}
```

I used [MVA (multi-valued attributes)](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/mva.html) on `category_ids` field, and it is the ARRAY type in Postgresql.

But I donot know How to define MVA on order_ids.  It will be through subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from sphinx forum....

```
sql_attr_multi = bigint order_ids from query; SELECT trade_id,id FROM orders ORDER BY trade_id
```

The first column of the query is the sphinx 'document_id' (ie the `id` in main `sql_query`)

The second column is the value to insert into the MVA array for that document.

(The `ORDER BY` might not strictly be needed, but sphinx is much quicker at processing the data if ordered by document_id IIRC)